# Define sequences as function of sequences using an equivalent at $\infty$?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits, analysis

I consider the sequence

$$
b_m = \left(\frac{-1}{log(1-1/m)}\right)\quad\text{and the function}\quad r(x) = \frac{1-e^{-1/x}}{x^{-2}e^{-1/x}}
$$

I found the following expression for the sequence

$$
a_m = r(b_m) = \frac{1-e^{\frac{-1}{\frac{-1}{log(1-1/m)}}}}{{log(1-1/m)^{-2}e^{\frac{-1}{\frac{-1}{log(1-1/m)}}}}} = = \frac{1-e^{log(1-1/m)}}{{log(1-1/m)^{-2}e^{log(1-1/m)}}} = \frac{1/m}{{log(1-1/m)^{-2}(1-1/m)}}
$$

However, my teacher finds this sequence

$$
a_m = r(b_m) = \frac{1-e^{-1/m}}{m^{-2}e^{-1/m}}
$$

using the fact that for $m\to\infty$ we have

$$
\frac{-1}{log(1-1/m)}\sim\frac{-1}{-1/m} = m
$$

however it seems not appropriate for me to use this equivalence since it is **when $m$ goes to $\infty$** however the sequence $a_m$ should be defined for all fixed $m$ (where it makes sense of course). So this does not seem correct for me and I would like to have your advice and know where I am wrong.

Thank you a lot !

Answer (score 1):

Reading the question, I supected a typo : it must be
$$r(x)= \frac{1-e^{-\frac 1x}}{x^{2}e^{-\frac 1x}}=\frac 1{x^2}\left(e^{\frac{1}{x}}-1\right) $$
So
$$b_m=-\frac{1}{\log \left(1-\frac{1}{m}\right)}\implies a_m=\frac{\log ^2\left(\frac{m-1}{m}\right)}{m-1}$$ which, expanded for large $m$ gives
$$a_m=\frac{1}{m^3}+\frac{2}{m^4}+O\left(\frac{1}{m^5}\right)$$ Doing the same for your teacher's solution (after fixing the sign in denominator)

$$a_m = r(b_m) = \frac{1-e^{-\frac 1m}}{m^{2}e^{-\frac 1 m}}=\frac{1}{m^3}+\frac{1}{2m^4}+O\left(\frac{1}{m^5}\right)$$